# Strange behavior when adding colorful UIImageView to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, alpha

I am attaching a colorful state indicator to the left of every UITableViewCell the following way:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(3, 1, 12, 42);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

switch (cellState)
        {
            case State_OK:
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                               [[UIColor customGreen] CGColor]);
                break;
            case State_Warning:
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                               [[UIColor customYellow] CGColor]);
                break;
            case State_Critical:
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                               [[UIColor customRed] CGColor]);
                break;
            case State_Unknown:
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                               [[UIColor customGray] CGColor]);
                break;
        }

        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
        imageView.alpha = 0.7;
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

return cell;
```

But somehow I am getting very strange colors:

[image]

When I set `imageView.alpha = 1;` The colors are fine again:

[image]

Adding the Images like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
cell.imageView.alpha = 0.7;
```

Works just fine! Even with `alpha`. But I don't really want to do it that way.

Comment: Well that makes sense, we you make the colours transparent (alpha lower then 1) the background colour will shine thru.

Comment: All cells have the same background color (light gray). So this cannot be the reason, since I am having different shades of each color for example.

Comment: Ofcourse it can, when the grey is is mixed with the colour of the cell above it wil change the colour.

Comment: But why should it be mixed the color of the cell above? That is the question.

Comment: Because you are make the imageview semi transparent when you set the alpha of the view. If you set it to 0.7 then means 30% of the view below will be shown thru.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be that the colours are blending with the background of the cell. What is the background color of the cell?

Another reason could be that your cells images are being reused, so you are setting the images on top previous images.

Comment: All cells have the same background color (light gray). So this cannot be the reason, since I am having different shades of each color for example.

Comment: That can be the reason, your color is 70% blended with the gray background, and that's the result

Comment: As I said. I am having different shades of the same color. See the images above. How can the same red be blended with the same gray two times resulting in different colors?

Comment: Reusing was the problem. Thanx.